# Can't bind callback function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am trying to call a callback function in the parent, which is triggered inside the child component. I already tried the different ways of binding, but I still can't get it to work. I always get this error.

```
Cannot read property 'logMessage' of undefined
```

My Parent

```
logMessage() {
    console.log("logMessage was called");
  }

return(
      <div>
        <h1>Blogs</h1>
        {this.state.campaigns.map(function(blog) {
          return (
            <div key={blog._id}>
              <CampaignCard blog={blog} callBack={() => this.logMessage()} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <Link to="/campaigns/add">
          <button>Add Blog</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
```

My child

```
  onConfirm={() => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
        this.props.callBack();
      }}
```

I can see that the callback function is called, but it still seems like `this` does not reference to the right place.

Comment: Did you bind `logMessage` in the component's constructor?

Comment: just use function return logMessage = () => { console.log("works"); }

Comment: you forgot to bind the map callback method, use arrow function there also, like this: `{this.state.campaigns.map((blog) => {....}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function for your `map`:

```
{this.state.campaigns.map((blog) => {
          return (
            <div key={blog._id}>
              <CampaignCard blog={blog} callBack={() => this.logMessage()} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Otherwise, `this` refers to the `map` callback context.

Answer (score 4):

```
 {this.state.campaigns.map(function(blog) {
          return (
            <div key={blog._id}>
              <CampaignCard blog={blog} callBack={() => this.logMessage()} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

It is because it is inside `map` and **for** `map` you didn't use an arrow function. Because of that `this` refers to whatever `this` is inside `map`.
Use something like:

```
render(){
let that = this;

.... // e.g. your map
    <CampaignCard blog={blog} callBack={() => that.logMessage()} />
...


}
```

Comment: Oddly enough he did not use the fat arrow for the map, but he did for the callback.

Comment: @MuratK. I had some problems understanding the arrow binding, but I think I understand it now.

Comment: @MuratK. yeah if he used arrow also in map it would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Two of some options

```
logMessage = () => {
   console.log("logMessage was called");
}
```

or

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.logMessage = this.logMessage.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function in the parent:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logMessage = this.logMessage.bind(this);
  }
```